# Unbind Objects in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: diagram, class-diagram, enterprise-architect

I have a class (let's call it "CLASS") in two different EA diagrams.
CLASS is the same object in both diagrams.
I want to change the attributes order in one diagram without it automatically changed in the other diagram too.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. As you note, it is the same element (avoid using the term "object" here; object is actually a type of element in UML, just like class, component, use case, etc).

Attributes can either be sorted alphabetically (by default) or in some custom order which you set manually, but EA stores this order with the class, not with the diagram. In other words, the attributes of one particular class will always be displayed in the same order in all diagrams.

New users often find this type of issue confusing or even frustrating, until they realize that *a diagram is only a visualization of the underlying model data* -- it is **not** a drawing. This is why you don't do search-and-replace in models: you make a change to an element in one place and it is immediately reflected wherever else that element is shown.

The only way to show two different attribute sort orders is to make a copy of the class, but then of course it's not the same element anymore.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on what you want. Do you want to show different aspects of the same element in the two diagrams then you can play with the **Feature and Compartment Visibility** (Ctrl-Shift-Y)

If you want to show different elements, but one starting as a copy of the other then you can **Copy** the element (Ctrl-C) and **Paste as duplicate** (Ctrl-Shift-V)

Answer (score 2):

You can not do that. And it does not make much sense to hide single attributes or methods of a class in specific diagrams. Either all or nothing (to show just the class). EA has a way to hide single stereotyped element parts for a whole diagram. But that's not what you're looking for.

Maybe you can explain WHY you want to do that.